# Talk me out of using sqlite and the django development server in a "production" environment?

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm using django as the CMS for a site-specific installation. Django will serve content under extremely limited and controlled circumstances to a handful of PC's running the installation software. It will literally be handling fewer than ten requests per day. The content it serves will simply be a once-a-day xml dump of the database, with no requirement that it be performant at all. It's ok if each request takes 30 seconds or more to complete.

I'd like the installation to be as simple as possible, and would love to not have to worry about installing apache and mysql, etc.

I know that sqllite and the development server are ABSOLUTELY NOT FOR PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENTS, but also that this warning primarily applies to public web sites, scalability, security, and other factors that won't affect this extremely sandboxed situation I'm working in.

Security and performance are usually mentioned as the two biggest reason not to use the development server in production. This installation will be on its own network, with no connection to the internet, so I'm not concerned about security. Performance is also a non-issue. Are there other factors I should be aware of that m Come on folks. Talk me out of this!

Comment: What about concurrent access to the database? SQLite needs accurate handling of concurrency to avoid undesirable situations...

Comment: @opalenzuela: with a single (single-threaded) process accessing SQLite it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: SQLite shouldn't be your worries, it is used in all kinds of production environments. However, Django's runserver might have memory leaks which would crash your environment. Try a frontend like gunicorn, which nicely integrates into Django and is easy to configure.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Agreed. As far as you keep that in mind it shouldn't be a problem ;)

Comment: If you're just running it as a local service that performs some tasks in the background, it should be fine... Though I'd suggest simply configuring apache or nginx, it's not hard.

Comment: My only argument against it in your case is just how easy it is to set up apache/mod_wsgi and something like mongodb with django I don't see a reason not to. In an hour you could easily make a shell or vagrant script to run the setup for you.

Comment: @morgancodes: for how long have you been in the business ? If less than 10 years, the "other factors you should be aware of" are that prototypes are never thrown away, one-off scripts get reused daily and that "extremely sandboxed" subsystems end up as public internet servers ;)

Answer (score 1):

DON'T use the built-in webserver in production. It's just not designed to be a good webserver. It's easy enough to have gunicorn run your django app just by passing commandline parameters.

DO use sqlite if the number of concurrent users at peak will be 3 or less. With much more than that, it's likely to become a significant bottleneck.

Comment: Do you have any data to back up '3 or less'?

Comment: @Joost Well technically two at once could be a problem, because it uses a global lock. I reckon you can get away with three, but if you're serious about doing this, you'll want to simulate traffic to figure out at what load it's going to be a problem.

Comment: So we are speaking about users who are changing data not who are viewing it only.